# Finding row wise average and average of all rows of space delimited file

Tags: python

I have a file which has many lines and each row would look like below:

```
10 55 19 51 2 9 96 64 60 2 45 39 99 60 34 100 33 71 49 13
77 3 32 100 68 90 44 100 10 52 96 95 36 50 96 39 81 25 26 13
```

Each line as numbers separated by space and each line( row is of different length)

How can I find the average of each row?

How can I find Sum of all the row wise averages?

Preferred language Python

Comment: wow, an army of programmers doing your homework for you, better give them some rep. I am missing the 'what I tried so far' part of your question

Comment: @Gullydwarf I am new to Stack Overflow. If you see below. I gave the answer myself :)  It was asked to me by some of other people. Not a homework though :P

Comment: @Sidnext2none hope all helped you

Comment: @Hackaholic Ofcourse. There is always learning in everything.

Comment: Being new is ok @Technopolice, but if you read the StackOverfow introduction you'll see that this question is not complete in this form and putting it on StackOverflow like this gives a bad representation of what StackOverflow is for, for any new people finding it.

Comment: @Gullydwarf I will keep that in mind for next time. Or should I delete the current question.

Comment: I would leave that to the people with mod powers. This is just my opinion of applying the StackOverflow rules. I have noticed feelings differ quite a bit about what should and what should not be allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code does the task mentioned:

```
def rowAverageSum(filename):
    import numpy as np
    FullMean = 0
    li = [map(int, x) for x in [i.strip().split() for i in open(filename).readlines()]]
    i=0
    while i<len(li):
        for k in li:
            print "Mean of row ",i+1,":",np.mean(k)
            FullMean+=np.mean(k)
            i+=1
    print "***************************"
    print "Grand Average:",FullMean
    print "***************************"
```

Comment: @GullyDwarf here u go.

Answer (score 0):

Using two utility functions `words` (to get the words in a line) and `average` (to get the average of a sequence of integers), I'd start wth something like

```
def words(s):
    return (w for w in s.strip().split())

def average(l):
    return sum(l) / len(l)

with open('input.txt') as f:
    averages = [average(map(int, words(line))) for line in f]
    total = sum(averages)
```

I like the `total = sum(averages)` part which very closely resembles your second requirement (the sum of all averages). :-)

I used `map(int, words(line))` (to convert a list of strings to a list of integers) simply because it's shorter than `[int(x) for x in words(line)]` even though the latter would most certainly be considered to be "more Pythonic".

Answer (score 0):

`3 / 2` is `1` in the Python. So you want to float result you should convert float.

`float(3) / 2` is `1.5`

```
>>> s = '''10 55 19 51 2 9 96 64 60 2 45 39 99 60 34 100 33 71 49 13
77 3 32 100 68 90 44 100 10 52 96 95 36 50 96 39 81 25 26 13'''
>>> line_averages = []
>>> for line in s.splitlines():
...     line_averages.append(sum([ float(ix) for ix in line.split()]) / len(line.split()))
... 
>>> line_averages
[45.55, 56.65]
>>> sum(line_averages) 
102.19999999999999
```

Or you can use `reduce`

```
>>> for line in s.splitlines():
...     line_averages.append(reduce(lambda x,y: int(x) + int(y), line.split()) / len(line.split()))
>>> line_averages
[45, 56]
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: int(x) + int(y), line_averages)
101
```

Answer (score 0):

how about trying this in a short way?

```
avg_per_row = [];
avg_all_row = 0;
f1 = open("myfile") # Default mode is read    
for line in f1:
    temp = line.split();
    avg = sum([int(x) for x in temp])/length(temp)
    avg_per_row.append(avg);   # Average per row
avg_all_row = sum(avg_per_row)/len(avg_per_row) # Average for all averages
```

Very compressed, but should work for you

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> f = open('yourfile')
>>> averages = [ sum(map(float,x.strip().split()))/len(x.strip().split()) for x in f ]
>>> averages
[45.55, 56.65]
>>> sum(averages)
102.19999999999999
>>> sum(averages)/len(averages)
51.099999999999994
```

`strip` removes '\n' then `split` will split on whitespace will give list of the numbers, map will convert all numbers to float type. sum will sum all numbers.

if you don't understand above code, you can see this , its same as above  but expanded :

```
>>> f = open('ll.txt')
>>> averages = []
>>> for x in f:
...     x = x.strip()   # removes newline character
...     x = x.split()   # split the lines on whitespaces and produces list of numbers
...     x = [ float(i) for i in x ]   # convert all number to type float
...     avg = sum(x)/len(x)           # calculate average ans store to variable avg
...     averages.append(avg)          # append the avg to list averages
... 
>>> averages
[45.55, 56.65]
>>> sum(averages)/len(averages)
51.099999999999994
```